# Vertical centering with flexbox when items have :after background images

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, pseudo-element, flexbox

How do I vertically center divs inside their container using flexbox if those divs have background images attached to their :after pseudo-element?

On Chrome 33 these divs align to the top: http://jsfiddle.net/6SQ6W/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left_and_right">
        <div>Left</div>
        <div>Right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

#container #left_and_right {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#container #left_and_right div, #container #left_and_right div:after {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
}

#container #left_and_right div {
    background: green;
    /* THIS PREVENTS VERTICAL CENTERING BUT SEEMS NEEDED FOR THE REST OF THE STUFF */
    position: absolute;
}

#container #left_and_right div:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(http://www.animatedgif.net/lipsmouth/kissing_e0.gif);
    text-indent: -9999px;
    left: 0;
}

#container #left_and_right div:nth-of-type(2) {
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should be using `position:`absolute` AND `display:flex`

Comment: You're probably right. So basically I should ditch flex in favor of display table or something?

Comment: It's not clear what it is you are trying to do but I've fiddled with your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/6SQ6W/4/

Comment: Basically those two lips should be centered vertically. In addition, the first lip should align to the left and the other to the right. Your fiddle comes incredibly close!

Comment: I believe the only thing missing is aligning the 2nd lip to the right? http://jsfiddle.net/6SQ6W/5/ -- thank you!

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/6SQ6W/7/

Comment: Marvellous! Thank you so much, have a great day!

Comment: @Paulie_D Could you add this as an answer so OP can mark it as correct?